# Android Compose Unit testing - Toggle a Switch

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Given a button with a `Modifier`:

```
TextButton(modified = Modifier.testTag("abc123"))
```

when you want to create a test to click it, you do:

```
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("abc123").performClick()
```

but when I'm having a:

```
Switch(modifier = Modifier.testTag("abc123"))
```

I'm trying every single perform gesture but I can't get the Switch to toggle, and can't get any documentation from Android.

What's the correct way to toggle it automatically in order to test it?

Answer (score 1):

I had issues toggling a switch with `performClick()`, but it turned out the switch wasn't visible on screen, `performClick()` will then simply click the coordinates (0,0) without any error.

So to ensure it's displayed first:

```
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("abc123")
   .assertIsDisplayed()
   .performClick()
```

**OLD ANSWER** (can still be used if you need to click something which is not displayed)

This seems to be a working way to toggle a material Switch in a Jetpack Compose test:

```
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("abc123")
   .performSemanticsAction(SemanticsActions.OnClick)
```

Comment: This is the same as `performClick()`

Comment: if you check the code `performClick()` is doing an actual tap, so it's not _the same_, however it is probably expected to have the same effect.
  
I've looked at this a bit more now and It seems that both `performClick()` and `performSemanticsAction(SemanticsActions.OnClick)` works fine in general on a `Switch`, I've tried to create a smaller test reproduce the scenario where only `performSemanticsAction` works but so far without luck...

Comment: Alright - so it turns out in my case it simply wasn't displayed :)
I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks Ulf. .performSemanticsAction(SemanticsActions.OnClick) worked for me. Always nice to see people you know having the same problems 

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still struggling with this, but the following seems to work for me:

```
composeTestRule
        .onNodeWithTag("abc123")
        .performGesture {  swipeLeft() } // or swipeRight to turn it on
```