# Android Compose: how to verify that a switch is on or off inside a unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-jetpack-compose, switch-component

I have a Switch in a composable:

```
Switch(
    checked = false,
    modifier = Modifier.testTag("mySwitch")
)
```

And I'm trying to verify it from a compose unit test:

```
composeTestRule.onAllNodesWithTag("mySwitch")
    .assertAll(isToggleable() and isOff())
```

However it fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to assertAll((ToggleableState is defined) && (ToggleableState = 'Off'))
Found '1' nodes not matching:
1) Node #8 at (l=955.0, t=387.0, r=1054.0, b=450.0)px, Tag: 'switch'
Has 4 siblings
Selector used: 'TestTag = 'mySwitch''
```

Apparently the Switch is neither toggleable or "on/off-eable". I've checked also with `assertIsToggleable` and `assertIsOff` separately, and both fail.

I've verified that the Switch is visible for the UI state used in the test.

Why does my test fail? It should be possible to easily test a freaking Switch. A Switch is the very definition of "Toggleable". How could I test it then, should I use custom semantic properties?

---

*DISCLAIMER: This question is not the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307655/android-compose-unit-testing-toggle-a-switch). I want to verify the Switch state, not to click it (that I will try later)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My test code was correct after all. `assertIs[Not]Toggleable`, `assertIsOff`, `assertIsOn`, and `assertAll(isToggleable())` should work on a Switch. But due to a bug (or weird undocumented feature) in Compose 1.2.1 a Switch is not marked as "Toggleable" unless you pass a callback as parameter.

I figured out this by inspecting the source code of `Switch.kt`. This is the part that causes the problem:

```
@Composable
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    fun Switch(
        checked: Boolean,
        onCheckedChange: ((Boolean) -> Unit)?,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        val toggleableModifier =
            if (onCheckedChange != null) {
                Modifier.toggleable(
                    value = checked,
                    onValueChange = onCheckedChange,
                    enabled = enabled,
                    role = Role.Switch,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = null
                )
            } else {
                Modifier
            }
```

As you can see, unless you pass the optional parameter `onCheckedChange`, the Switch is not made Toggleable. And that in turn will cause all the `isToggleable`-like assertions to throw an exception, and the same will happen with the `isOn` and `isOff` assertions since they also require the node to be "Toggleable".

So passing a dummy `onCheckedChange` lambda to the switch in the test code solved the problem:

```
Switch(checked=True,onCheckedChange={})
```

Comment: Can you please post the full code and test code example? I can't get it working to toggle the `Switch` from on to off in the test.

Comment: @JJD I have updated the answer. Check the final line.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this without success. Can you please also post your test code?

Answer (score -1):

## Test

You can use `.assertIsOn()` inside the test.

```
private val checked = mutableStateOf(false)

@Before
fun launchContent() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        SharedComponentsTheme {
            Switch(
                checked = checked.value,
                onCheckedChange = { checked.value = !checked.value }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Test
fun testSwitchOn() {
    checked.value = false
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("SWITCH_TAG")
        .performTouchInput { click() }
        .assertIsOn()
}
```

## Code

In the code you need to set the `toggleableState` to `On` or `Off`

```
import androidx.compose.ui.state.ToggleableState.On
import androidx.compose.ui.state.ToggleableState.Off
import androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role.Switch

@Composable
fun Switch(
    checked: Boolean,
    onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
) {
    androidx.compose.material3.Switch(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clearAndSetSemantics {
                testTag = "SWITCH_TAG",
                role = Switch,
                toggleableState = if (checked) {
                    On
                } else {
                    Off
                }
            },
        checked = checked,
        onCheckedChange = { onCheckedChange(it) }
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes we should be able to, but it doesnt work unless `onCheckedChange` is explicitly passed.